# javascript is affecting every anchor, I want to make some exempt

Tags: javascript, scroll, popup, anchor

so I have one script that scrolls the whole page smoothly. Nice script. It uses anchors to do this. So the NAvigation Menu basically says "ABOUT ME" or whatever, and when clicked the whole page scrolls to the ABOUT ME section. But what its programmed to do is when I click on an internal anchor link, it bring the browser view to the TOP, LEFT. which works fine, since I want to scroll the entire page.

BUT.

I am using another script that allows me to click an option on a menu, and a little window should pop up and give me the info. BUT instead, the whole page moves, thanks to the previous scrolling script, and puts the new pop TOP, LEFT.

Soooo? any ideas?

```
init: function () {
    var lnks = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    for (var i = 0, lnk; lnk = lnks[i]; i++) {
        if ((lnk.href && lnk.href.indexOf('#') != -1) && ((lnk.pathname == location.pathname) || ('/' + lnk.pathname == location.pathname)) && (lnk.search == location.search)) {
            addEvent(lnk, 'click', HtinyScrolling.initScroll, false);
            lnk.onclick = function () {
                return false;
            } // Safari 
        }
    }
```

Comment: "any ideas?" Sure. Rewrite the scrolling script so that it only affects the desired anchors.

Comment: Your question is unclear, but, if you want certain anchors to not be affected, you can omit them from your original selection with the not function.  http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/

Comment: @AdamRackis: Is jQuery being used here?

Comment: @RightSaidFred - I assumed it was.  I can't think of any reason anyone wouldn't use jQuery in a website in 2011, but I guess that assumption was wrong based on OP's comment

Comment: @AdamRackis: I can. More so than ever in 2011.

Comment: @RightSaidFred - why can you see that more so than ever in 2011?  Does jQuery not play well with mobile devices?

Comment: @AdamRackis: Because browser compatibility is getting better and better. I just don't see as much reason to use a non-standard API. It would be nice if jQuery was more modular so a person could cherry-pick  only the desired parts.

Comment: @RightSaidFred - Well I'm glad compatibility is getting better, but I'd rather get dental work done than deal with crap like `var lnks = document.getElementsByTagName('a');`  A non-standard api (that's widely used and stable, and < 100K) seems like a tiny price to pay for better, more maintainable code—  $("a")

Comment: @AdamRackis: Understood. I'm just not as enthralled with jQuery as some are. It has its ups and downs. I don't see it as necessarily making code better or maintainable though. There's plenty of horrendous jQuery-centric code that comes across SO.

Comment: @RightSaidFred Fair enough - I've only been hanging around the JavaScript tag for a week or so, so I can only imagine the jQuery crap you've seen from junior devs.  It's all too easy to try and make a great tool into a panacea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewrite the scrolling script so it does not affect the anchors in the menu. Without seeing any code it is difficult for me to say exactly what to change.

The best way to solve this would be to either make the scrolling script only affect anchors of a specific css class such as `.scrollable`, or alternatively make it not affect anchors with a specific class for example if the option menu has every option with class `.option` then disable your script for anchors with class `.option`. If I could see the relevant parts of your code I could help further

Comment: `code`init: function() {
  var lnks = document.getElementsByTagName('a');   
  for(var i = 0, lnk; lnk = lnks[i]; i++) {   
   if ((lnk.href && lnk.href.indexOf('#') != -1) &&  ( (lnk.pathname == location.pathname) ||
   ('/'+lnk.pathname == location.pathname) ) && (lnk.search == location.search)) {  
   addEvent(lnk,'click',HtinyScrolling.initScroll,false);
   lnk.onclick=function(){return false;} // Safari
   }   
  }